# Yarn script produces different output than running command directly

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts, prettier

I have a script defined in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "prettierCheck": "./node_modules/.bin/prettier --check ./app/javascript/**/*.js"
}
```

If I run this script using `yarn run prettierCheck`, Prettier does not find any formatting issues with my files. However, if I run the Prettier command directly, it finds violating files.

Output of `yarn run prettierCheck`:

```
~/Projects/tome $ yarn run prettierCheck
yarn run v1.19.0
$ ./node_modules/.bin/prettier --check ./app/javascript/**/*.js
Checking formatting...
All matched files use Prettier code style!
Done in 0.20s
```

Output of `./node_modules/.bin/prettier --check ./app/javascript/**/*.js`:

```
~/Projects/tome $ ./node_modules/.bin/prettier --check ./app/javascript/**/*.js
Checking formatting...
{... several files listed here ...}
Code style issues found in the above file(s). Forgot to run Prettier?
```

Why does this happen? What is the difference between running the command directly vs. through a Yarn script?

Comment: what is the command you are using to check directly?

Comment: @AnshuKumar exactly the same thing as the `prettierCheck` script, just executed directly at the prompt.

Comment: Can you include the output from both executions? Is it possible that it yarn thinks it is executing from a different directory and therefore not finding the files passed in? does anything change if you drop the `./node_modules/.bin/` prefix from the command (it's redundant)?

Comment: @Soc no difference if I drop the prefix or not. Updated my question with the output from both runs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue or at least I thought I had the same issue. I ***tried a few things like adding quotes to the file/dir/glob in my command***, changing my paths/globs & it started working for me because now I could see some useful output. Try these & maybe it'll work for you guys as well.

This is what [prettier CLI documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html) has to say about paths & file/dir/globs.

> Don't forget the quotes around the globs! The quotes make sure that
>   Prettier CLI expands the globs rather than your shell, which is
>   important for cross-platform usage.

So try something like this in your *scripts* (***Note:*** -c is short for --check)

```
scripts": {
"pretty-check": "prettier -c 'src/**/*.ts'",
}
```

Notice the quotes around `'src/**/*.ts'`
I'm not sure if this would work for everyone but I'm hoping that it does as it did for me.

And if you are wondering ***What is file/dir/glob*** 
It's basically the part where you define the regex for your files like the part `'src/**/*.ts'` in the command `prettier -c 'src/**/*.ts'`